# Wave Equation with Constant Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to find a formal solution to

\begin{eqnarray}
&u_{tt} &= c^2 u_{xx}, \;\;\;0<x<1, \mathrm{and \;}t>0\\
&u(x,0)&=x+1,\\
&u_t(x,0)&=x(1-x), \;\;\;\;0 \leq x \leq 1\\
&u(0,t) &= 1,\\
&u(1,t)&= 2, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; t\geq 0
\end{eqnarray}

I tried doing separation of variables and assuming $u(x,t)=X(x)\cdot T(t)$, but the boundary conditions are confusing me.

I get $X^{\prime\prime}(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$, so $X(x) = \alpha e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+\beta e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$. When I use $X(0)=1$ and $X(1)=2$, I get,

\begin{eqnarray}
\beta &=& \frac{2-e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}}{e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}+e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}}\\
\alpha&=& \frac{2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}+e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}-2}{e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}}+e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}}},
\end{eqnarray}

but I feel like this isn't leading me in the right direction. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! This question is a problem that doesn't require techniques in computational science, and it's probably a better fit for Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Is there a typo in the equation in the last term? Did you mean to say $u_{xx}$ instead of $xx$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I put + instead of _. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Separation of variables works only for homogeneous boundary conditions. Begin by reducing to homogeneous by subtracting off a solution of the PDE which satisfies the  boundary conditions. Namely, let $v(x,y) = u(x,y)-1-x$. The new function satisfies
$$
\begin{split}
 v_{tt} &= c^2 v_{xx}, \quad 0<x<1, \mathrm{and \;}t>0\\
 v(x,0) &= 0,\\
v_t(x,0)&=x(1-x), \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
 v(0,t) &= 0,\\
 v(1,t) &= 0, \qquad t\geq 0
\end{split}
$$
The rest is standard:  solve $X''+\lambda X=0$, getting $X_n(x) = \sin \pi nx$ and $\lambda = (\pi n)^2$. Then look for the coefficients in $$u(x,t)= (A_n \cos \pi n t+B_n \sin \pi n t) \sin \pi n x$$ 
that match the initial conditions.

Comment: Ahh, yes! Thank you!